# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, observable

Declared in service like this:

```
public currentDBUserBS$: any;

constructor(private afDb: AngularFireDatabase){}

fetchUser(uid){
  this.afDb.object(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe((dUser) => {
    if (dUser) {
      this.currentDBUserBS$ = dUser;
    }
  });
}
```

Now trying to use in template

```
template: `<li *ngIf="(authService.currentDBUserBS$ | async)?.role=='admin'"> Something </li>`
```

The error stack:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4219)
    at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:5630)
    at AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:5612)
    at AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:5586)
    at Object.View_AppNavigatorComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (AppNavigatorComponent.html:40)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13514)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44868715/3055401

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are giving `currentDBUserBS$` the object you are fetching from Firebase and not the Observable. If you want to do it this way, you have to remove the `| async` in your template.

However, you could do the following :

```
fetchUser(uid){
  this.currentDBUserBS$ = this.afDb.object(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges();
}
```

`.valueChanges()` gives you an observable and will update automatically when a new value is emitted or an existing value is modified.

Comment: ok got it, but is there any difference between the two approaches ? In both cases I would get asynchronus update to my template from db right ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 the results will almost be the same. The `| async` is used to subscribe to your Observable / BehaviorSubject / Subject in your template. When a new value is emitted, Angular will be notified of the changes. With a `.subscribe`, it will be checked every change detection cycle.

Answer (score 4):

You must add `.valueChanges();` after subscribing operation. It is required as shown below:

```
 this.courses$=db.list('/courses').valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass array to async pipe instead of Observable. Just remove the async pipe or assign observable to currentDBUserBS$.

Comment: db.object() return object db.list() returns array