# Error with Ionic 3, Firebase and angularfire2

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I've got the following error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

when I try to list data from my firebase DB, and I don't know why. See my codes, my **related deps**:

```
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.9.2",
...
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
"firebase": "^5.2.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
```

my **service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Item } from './../../models/item/item.model';

@Injectable()
export class ShoppingListService {

  private shoppingListRef;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.shoppingListRef = this.db.list<Item>('shopping-list');
  }

  getShoppingList() {
    return this.shoppingListRef;
  }

}
```

my **component**:

```
...
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  shoppingList$: Observable<Item[]>

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private shopping: ShoppingListService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shoppingList$ = this.shopping
    .getShoppingList()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(changes => {
      return changes.map(change => {
        let retorno = {
          key: change.payload.key,
          ...change.payload.val()
        };
        return retorno;
      });
    });
  }
...
```

And finally my **template**:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingList$ | async">
   {{item.name}}
</ion-item>
```

I've got the same error if I remove the `async` pipe. And I've been tried this question without success:
[Angular 4: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866124/angular-4-invalidpipeargument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe)

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the old way to retrieve data from angularfire2, now I make it work just with this:

in my **component**:

```
...
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  shoppingList$: Observable<Item[]>

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private shopping: ShoppingListService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shoppingList$ = this.shopping
    .getShoppingList()
    .valueChanges();
  }
...
```

And all works fine.